# vscode python unresolved reference to module in subfolder when using venv and language server

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, python-language-server

I've opted to use the Python Language Server instead of Jedi.

My project root folder has a subfolder named "cdk_app", and in that folder is file cdk_app_stack.py.  That file defines class "Lemoncello"

in the project root folder my file app.py has this line:

```
from cdk_app.cdk_app_stack import Lemoncello
```

"cdk_app.cdk_app_stack" is marked by vscode as an unresolved reference. (but it runs properly.)

if I change it to

```
cdk_app_stack import Lemoncello
```

(removed the folder qualifier) vscode resolves it ok (and it runs ok)

this is only an issue when I use the project venv.  When not, both syntax resolve and run.

Why is the reference unresolvable when I specify the subfolder name, when using a venv?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem involved easy-install.pth in my python site-packages folder.  This file was created by the AWS CDK installer (I believe).  It had a reference to the venv subfolder. This is all quite proper, but the Python Language Server doesn't handle it well. If I removed this pth file, the problem went away.  Of course, that's just a workaround, and Python Language Server will presumably work better in this scenario, someday.

For some chatter about a different language server issue with pth files, see https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/537

To turn off the language server, configure vscode as "python.jediEnabled": true (which is the default.)